# Curious properties of 79 and 859 in sums of two Fibonacci numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $\mathrm{Fib}_2$ be the set of sums of two Fibonacci numbers:
$$\mathrm{Fib}_2 = \{ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 18, 21, 22, 23, 24, 26, \dots \}. $$

The elements in $\mathrm{Fib}_2$ have various prime divisors. I found some curious properties about prime divisors.

1. If we gather remainders of multiples of $79$ divided by $859$, then they seems to be restricted to 9 numbers. That is,
   $$\{ 79a~\mathrm{mod}~859 : 79a \in \mathrm{Fib}_2 \} = \{ 0, 65, 385, 490, 491, 621, 624, 764, 846 \}.$$
2. The frequency of remainder $0$ suppresses other cases. For sums of two Fibonacci numbers $< 10^{100}$, the 9 remainders appear as follows:
   \begin{array}{lllll}
   0:879, & 65:72, & 385:36, & 490:72, & 491:72, \\
   621:84, & 624:72, & 764:72, & 846:78
   \end{array}
3. If an element in $\mathrm{Fib}_2$ is divisible by $859$, then it is divisible by $79$.

Another pair is 139 and 461. Consider sums of two Fibonacci numbers $< 10^{100}$. The remainders of multiples of 139 divided by 461 are only two cases: 0 and 322. They appear 1445 times and 210 times, respectively. Also, the multiple of $461$ in $\mathrm{Fib}_2$ is divisible by $139$.

(229, 95419) and (263, 967) are also such pairs.

Are these observations true? That is, do the following conditions hold for those pairs $(a, b)$? Also, how many such pairs exist?

1. The remainders of multiples of $a$ in $\mathrm{Fib}_2$ divided by $b$ are very restricted.
2. The frequency of remainder 0 suppresses other cases.
3. The multiples of $b$ in $\mathrm{Fib}_2$ are divisible by $a$.

Comment: For what it's worth, the sums of two Fibonaccis are tabulated at http://oeis.org/A084176 But I think the first thing to do is to write down all the remainders of Fibonacci numbers modulo 79.

Comment: So these are quite special properties of Fibonacci sequences modulo 79 and 859. (See [Pisano period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisano_period).) In order to check these properties, it suffices to look at all pairs of the first $LCM(\pi(79),\pi(859))$ Fibonacci numbers. It does not explain why and when this happens. Maybe it is just a coincidence: there are many pairs of numbers, and sometimes we get lucky...

Comment: The Pisano periods $\pi(79)$ and $\pi(859)$ are both $78$.

Comment: @IvanIzmestiev Thank you. I didn't know about Pisano period. It's interesting.

Comment: Tables of Fibonacci entry points: Part One (pub. The Fibonacci Assciation, Jan 1965) http://www.fq.math.ca/Books/Complete/entrypoints1.pdf, p.44 (of the PDF; p.28 of the typed version) is a table of primes $p$ and their entry points $Z(p)$, ordered by $Z(p)$. From that table it can be seen that $Z(79)=Z(859)=78$, etc. p's entry point $Z(p)$ divides, but might be less than, its Pisano period. E.g. $Z(37)=Z(113)=19$ but their Pisano periods are 76.  Entry points are still relevant, though, because it says which $F_n$ $p$ divides: $p\mid F(n)\iff Z(p)\mid n$.